# Natbib and makebst: For three authors, natbib is truncating citations

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, custom-bib

I'm using `natbib`, and a `.bst` file generated by me with `latex makebst`. This `.bst` only puts `et al.` if citation has more than three authors.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\providecommand{\BIBand}{e}
\begin{document}
Citation \cite{Kim2010}
\bibliographystyle{tesetres}
\bibliography{library}
\end{document}
```

However, I'm getting this result:

> Citation KIM (SON e JEONG)

and if I comment the second line (and stop using `natbib`), I get this:

> Citation [KIM, SON e JEONG, 2010]

I don't know why `natbib` is truncating the citation.
Anyone could help me?

My files:
http://vps.fmvz.usp.br/~grisi/tesetres.bst
http://vps.fmvz.usp.br/~grisi/makebst.log
http://vps.fmvz.usp.br/~grisi/library.bib
library.bib:

```
@article{Kim2010,
author = {KIM, Youngdo and SON, Seung-Woo and JEONG, Hawoong},
doi = {10.1103/PhysRevE.81.016103},
issn = {1539-3755},
journal = {Physical Review E},
number = {1},
pages = {1--9},
title = {{Finding communities in directed networks}},
url = {http://link.aps.org/doi/10.1103/PhysRevE.81.016103},
volume = {81},
year = {2010}
}
```

Edit:
I discovered that this happen only with commands `\cite` and `\citet`. When using `\citep` the output is normal.

> Citation (KIM, SON e JEONG 2010)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that something went wrong when you created the custom bibliography style file `tesetres.bst`. Not having access to the log file, it's nearly hopeless to try to parse the actual `.bst` file to find out what's going on. Your best bet may be to rerun the `makebst` utility from scratch.

Comment: I've tried that already, 5 times.

Comment: This is the log file:
http://vps.fmvz.usp.br/~grisi/makebst.log

Comment: @ZeGrisi - Thanks for providing this additional link. The log file shows -- see question `<<AUTHOR--YEAR SUPPORT SYSTEM (if author-year citations)` -- that you've chosen to optimize the `.bst` file for use with the `apalike` citation package. However, according to the MWE you posted, you actually use the `natbib` package. Do the problems you report persist if you rerun `makebst` with optimization set for the `natbib` package?

Comment: [I found a post in another forum](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=18402) suggesting this. Aaaaand it works!!! However, I was forgetting to re-run bibtex, so I was stuck until now. Thank you!